# Is it appropriate to publish a geofeed for an IP address I don't directly own?

Tags: routing-registry

As a quick background, a geofeed is a CSV file published by network operators containing location data for individual IP addresses and/or prefixes. It's in the format `Prefix,Country Code,ISO 3166-2 Region Code,City,Zip`. For example, a line may look like `193.0.24.0/21,NL,NL-ZH,Rotterdam,12345`.

The organization I manage has blocks of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (and an ASN, if that's relevant). I have published an [RFC 8805-compliant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8805) geofeed for all of them, and several geolocation databases (e.g., MaxMind) are actively using said geofeed. The geofeed is also published in the corresponding `inetnum` and `inet6num` objects.

Aside from the addresses we directly own, the upstream ISP has also allocated several static IPs for us. However, their geolocation is wrong and it occasionally tangibly affects things (e.g. Ookla Speed Test selecting a faraway city).

**My question is**, since those static IP addresses are practically permanently allocated to my organization, is it appropriate of me to include those in my geofeed?

In my limited research, I do not see any guidelines for and/or against it, so I'm leaning towards including them and correcting those geolocations myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd include those IP addresses in the feed. After all, you are the one using them.

I'd notify the ISP however, and make sure that the records are removed in case you lose the addresses in the future.

Comment: Everyone was cool with it and the major databases (e.g., MaxMind) accepted the changes. All is well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control the geofeed for "A", including it in the feed you do control for "B" should do absolutely nothing. No one will fetch your feed looking for "A", because nothing points there. When someone does fetch your file, they *SHOULD* ignore your "cache poisoning" attempt. (otherwise, *anyone* could claim anything about any address.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the IP address into your geofeed file. Please make sure it is correct and always up-to-date.

I don't see any risk here other than you geofeed file blacklisted if someone complaint on any incorrect information.